# Linking webview with another activity

Tags: android, android-activity, webview, hyperlink

My problem is a link that i create in webview didn't work, and then when i click it, it wont go to another Activity, so where's my error?
Help, please!!! Thank you

```
prknln1.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset",Perkenalan,"text/html","utf-8",null);
        prknln1.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                Intent i;
                {
                    if (url.equalsIgnoreCase("TabHiragana")) {
                        i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TabHiragana.class);
                        startActivity(i);
                    } else if (url.equalsIgnoreCase("TabKatakana")) {
                        i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TabKatakana.class);
                        startActivity(i);
                    } else if (url.equalsIgnoreCase("Kanji")) {
                        i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), List_Kanji.class);
                        startActivity(i);
                    }
                }
                Log.e("URL", "URL" + url);
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Comment: Your question is not clear

Comment: i create link to another activity in webview, when i use loadData it works, but when i change it to loadDataWithBaseURL it doesn't work, and there's no error warning. So where's the problem about my code... Thank you

Comment: what you are getting in `Log.e("URL", "URL" + url);` in logs when clicking on link inside webView?

Comment: i'm sorry, i didn't run it on emulator but in my cellphone, so i didn't know what i got in logs. But now my problem has been solved, i only change equalsIgnoreCase with contains. Thank you for ur time... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you will be checking the particular word in the url, for that you need to use **contains** method.

```
prknln1.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset",Perkenalan,"text/html","utf-8",null);
        prknln1.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                Intent i;
                {
                    if (url.contains("TabHiragana")) {
                        i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TabHiragana.class);
                        startActivity(i);
                    } else if (url.contains("TabKatakana")) {
                        i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TabKatakana.class);
                        startActivity(i);
                    } else if (url.contains("Kanji")) {
                        i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), List_Kanji.class);
                        startActivity(i);
                    }
                }
                Log.e("URL", "URL" + url);
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Comment: i'll try, but when i use loadData only on first line it works, but when i use loadDataWithBaseURL why it doesn't work?? Can you explain it... thank you Mr. Kumar

Comment: with loadData(String data, String mimeType, String encoding) we can't able to specify the base url, but with loadDataWithBaseURL(String baseUrl, String data, String mimeType, String encoding, String historyUrl) we can able to specify the base url. For example  path to asset folder.

Comment: yeayyy!!!... It works. Thank you, but
What's the different between contains and equalsIgnoreCase?

Comment: **contains** will check whether  that particular string is present or not(it may be a part of the string), but the **equalsIgnoreCase** will try to match complete strings by ignoring the case.

Comment: contains() checks if a String contains another String while equalsIgnoreCase() checks if two Strings are equal. That was your issue

Answer (score 0):

To open an activity and pass a parameter to it:

In your text data (myText), have the url:

```
"<a href=\"" + word + "\">" + word + "</a>"
```

Load data:

```
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset", myText, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

setWebViewClient:

```
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                if (url.startsWith("file")) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MyActivity.this, MyActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("word", Uri.parse(url).getLastPathSegment());
                    startActivity(intent);
                    return true;
                } else
                    return false;
            }
        });
```